# Getting all branches from bitbucket

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, bitbucket

I need to hand off a visual studio project that has multiple branches. Bitbucket is being used as the repo. I am trying to find a way to download the entire repo with every branch. I'm not sure if there is a solution using GIT or some feature in bitbucket that I can't find. When I try to download directly from Bitbucket I only get the master branch

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason why you can't just `git fetch` from the repository:

```
git fetch origin
```

This should pull in every remote branch to whatever local machine from which you issue this command.  If you need to access a particular branch, you could just check it out via:

```
git checkout some_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Team Explorer => Open your repository => Select 'Branches' tab => Right click your repository => click 'Create local branch from' => choose source branch from dropdown with name /origin/branchname

Comment: I did a walk through. My option was "New Local Branch From", but it looks like the same methodology. I'll be trying it in about an hour. I'll let you know how it turned out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to download all branches so I could send them to a client via FTP who I couldn't give repository access to. The following worked:

git archive --format zip --output ~/pathToWhereYouWantToSave HEAD